# How can I create a custom UIView class in swift with numerous initializers?

Tags: swift, uiview, initialization

I'm trying to stick this out and learn it and write an app in Swift, and not default to Obj-C, although I keep getting stuck on very simple things and can't seem to find my answers online. The temptation to go back is strong. Here's what I'm trying to do.

```
class CircleView : UIView {

    var title: UILabel

    convenience init(frame: CGRect, title: String) {

    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.title = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height))
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("CircleView is not NSCoding compliant")
    }
}
```

What my intended goal is... whoever creates an instance of CircleView should have to provide both a frame and a string. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're pretty close. The convenience initializer can set the label and then call the designated initializer:

```
class CircleView : UIView {

    var title: UILabel

    convenience init(frame: CGRect, title: String) {
        self.init(frame: frame)
        self.title.text = title
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.title = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height))
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("CircleView is not NSCoding compliant")
    }
}
```

The only caveat here is that someone could still call the designated initializer directly, without providing text for the label. If you don't want to allow that, I believe you could just make the designated initializer private, i.e. :

```
private override init(frame: CGRect) { ... }
```